# how to create and download zip file without path directory

Tags: php

My code creates a ZIP file and downloads it in this ZIP folder some images exist.

It’s done well but problem is that after I download and extract this folder then all path folder also become my code is:

```php
$id         = $row['id'];
$doc_name   = $row['doc_name'];
$file_names = explode(',',$doc_name);
$file_path  = $_ROOT_REQUIRE."uploads/document/";
$archive_file_name = "demo.zip";
$zip        = new ZipArchive($archive_file_name);
if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE ) !== TRUE) {
    echo "cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n";
    exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
}
foreach ($file_names as $files) {
    if ($files !== '') {
        $zip->addFile("$files", basename($files));
    }
} 
$zip->close();
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($archive_file_name).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archive_file_name));
header('Cache-Control: private');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile(basename($archive_file_name));
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code look's is Fine.
Just Replace Your Foreach Loop .

```
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);          
    if(filetype($file) == 'file') {         
        $zip->addFile( $file, pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME ) );
    }
}
```

it should be work
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear on why this would be happening, looking at this line:

```
$zip->addFile("$files", basename($files));
```

Why are there `"` quotes around `$files`?  I would recommend changing that to:

```
$zip->addFile($files, basename($files));
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes I made and it work well now. Thanks to all.

1. `$overwrite = true;`
2. `if($zip->open($archive_file_name,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true)`
3. This larger piece:

   ```
   foreach ($file_names as $file) {
       $files = $file_path.$file;
       $files = str_replace('\\', '/', $files);          
       if(filetype($files) == 'file') {
           $zip->addFile( $files, pathinfo( $files, PATHINFO_BASENAME ) );
       }
   }
   ```